# How to remove Magento 2 default mobile menu, so that i can use my own custom menu?

Tags: magento2, rwd

I would like to know where is the default mobile menu located in magento 2. My problem is i created my own custom responsive menu but it defaults to the mobile menu after 768px. Followed several tutorials and none are working.

Theme in use: Freego Responsive Theme
Magento Vers: Magento 2.3

FYI: Freego theme uses Magento Blank theme as its parent theme if that helps.

10/24/19

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Freego theme, navigation menu comes from topmenu.phtml file which is located at

```
app/design/frontend/Solwin/freego/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml
```

location. So put your responsive navigation menu code in ***topmenu.phtml*** file.